# $EDITOR environment variable won't set

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables, webmin

Whenever I attempt to set the EDITOR environment variable, a subsequent check reveals no value has been set.

I was attempting to edit the crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e -u mycooluser
```

which returns:

```
no crontab for mycooluser - using an empty one
Error opening terminal: unknown.
crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 1
```

I then found this post:
[Setup a cronjob from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372570/setup-a-cronjob-from-commandline) which suggested I change the editor used.

So I tried (including variations):

```
export EDITOR="/bin/nano"
export EDITOR="usr/bin/nano"
export EDITOR=nano
```

and when I execute (per this link [How do I find and set my $EDITOR environment variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432524/how-do-i-find-and-set-my-editor-environment-variable)):

```
echo $EDITOR
```

OR

```
printenv | grep EDITOR
```

I get nothing, a quick `printenv` check also confirms that no `EDITOR` variable exists in the list. To be clear, by 'nothing' I mean that on the `echo $EDITOR` it prints a blank line and for `printenv | grep EDITOR` nothing is printed.

**Any idea why the variable isn't being set or why I can't seem to change it?**

System:
Ubuntu 18.04.1, Using Terminal in Webmin

Comment: You do *not* get a message like `EDITOR: readonly variable` when attempting to set the value, correct?

Comment: Correct, I do not, when I set the value, it acts as though it was executed with no other messages displayed.

Comment: What happens if you try `EDITOR="/bin/nano" crontab -e`?

Comment: It returns the following: `Error opening terminal: unknown.
crontab: "/bin/nano" exited with status 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the so-called "popup shell".  This is not a terminal.  Nor is it in fact really a shell.

It's a piece of user interface fakery inside a WWW browser that executes shell commands separately from one another as individual transactions.  There's no actual continually running shell to hold an environment variable.  It is merely presented that way by the user interface in the WWW browser.  The shell commands are run in a nonce process environment where no `TERM` environment variable has been set, and in a session with no controlling terminal.  And even if it *were* set, there's no terminal emulator to handle the terminal I/O that full-screen programs like text editors use.  Indeed, there is only provision for relaying output of the program back to the local machine; no input is sent in the other direction.

`nano`, `pico`, and `emacs` will complain about being unable to determine the terminal type and open the terminal.  VIM and NeoVIM fall back to assumptions that simply do not hold in this case, and give the appearance of simply hanging.  Not even line-mode editors like `ex` and `ed` will work as user input is simply not sent to the remote machine.  (One possibly could drive `ex` *non-interactively* with its `-c` option.)  Similarly, one cannot change passwords with the `passwd` command.

This has been a misunderstanding of the "popup shell" since at least 2016.

## Further reading

- "JedMeister" (2018-03-04).  *[Interactive Terminal](https://github.com/authentic-theme/authentic-theme/issues/1037)*. Bug #1037.  authentic-theme bugs.
- Michael Hurt (2018-11-13). *[Error opening terminal: unknown](https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/bugs/5214/)*. Bug #5214.  Webmin bugs.
- "7starsone" (2016-12-08).  *[File Manager: Command line](https://github.com/authentic-theme/authentic-theme/issues/566#issuecomment-265679356)*.  Bug #566.  authentic-theme bugs.

Comment: I decided to SSH into the server and then run the crontab commands and it worked just fine, thanks for the info I had no idea! Even the `history` command doesn't show a single thing I've typed into the "popup shell".

Comment: I think I heard you say that this was an opportunity for `ed`!

Comment: Recent versions of the theme would raise internal editor, upon calling _edit, nano, vi_ and etc for _path/to/file_ in inbuilt Command Shell port.